# I need to display a soundcloud iframe in a uiwebview. Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I need to add an embedded iframe soundcloud player in a uiwebview i have tried it serveral ways but it either doesnt load at all or the iframe loads but when I press play the track doesnt play at all I have used this code however it loads the 
iframe but doesn't play it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    self.titleLbl.text = self.video.videoTitle;
    self.descLbl.text = self.video.videoDescription;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.video.videoIframe baseURL:nil];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *css = @".container {position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%; } .track { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}";

    NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
                    "styleNode.type = \"text/css\";\n"
                    "var styleText = document.createTextNode('%@');\n"
                    "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n",css];
    NSLog(@"js:\n%@",js);
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soundcloud iframe doesn't work with UIWebView swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956105/soundcloud-iframe-doesnt-work-with-uiwebview-swift)

Comment: WKwebview should work though but its too much of a hassle to bring it in programatically